# How can i add an word or text doc attachment?

Tags: python

How can I add a line that will send a word or text doc as an attachment? all of the documentation that I've seen is written differently but I can't get it to work.

I thought the `sendpdf` module would work but it didn't work when I installed it

below is the code --

```
def mail():
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    s.starttls()
    SUBJECT = "Hello"
    TEXT = "message for the body."
    receiver = "a@gmail.com, b@gmail.com".split(",")
    message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(SUBJECT, TEXT)
    s.login(username, password)
    s.sendmail(username, receiver, message)
    s.quit()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it may need to use module standard `email` which can read data from file and add to mail as `attachment`. OR you whould have to learn how to create `attachment` using pure text. It may need to add special headers about multi content, and read data from file and add it as `multi-part`

Comment: see Python documentation: [email.examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html). In one example you can see `msg.add_attachment(...)`

Answer (score 0):

To add attachement you have to add special header, read text in bytes mode, convert it to `base64` and add it to mail with special lines which show where is beginning and end of file data.
So it is complex task.

But python has standard module [email](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html) and submodule [email.message](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html) with object `EmailMessage` to easily create email with attachement.

See also: [email.examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) and search `add_attachment`

```
from email.message import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = "Hello"
msg['From']    = "your_email@gmail.com"
msg['To']      = "a@gmail.com, b@gmail.com"
msg.preamble   = "message for the body."

with open('folder/filename.txt', 'rb') as fp:
    data = fp.read()

msg.add_attachment(data, maintype='text', subtype='plain', filename="filename.txt")
```

And now you can send it using `s.send_message(msg)`

```
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
s.starttls()
s.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD)

#s.sendmail(username, receiver, message)
s.send_message(msg)

s.quit()
```

Full code:

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

# --- create the container email message ---

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = "Hello"
msg['From']    = "your_email@gmail.com"
msg['To']      = "a@gmail.com, b@gmail.com"
msg.preamble   = "message for the body."

with open('folder/filename.txt', 'rb') as fp:
    data = fp.read()

msg.add_attachment(data, maintype='text', subtype='plain', filename="filename.txt")

#print(msg.as_string())

# --- send email ---

LOGIN    = 'your_email@gmail.com'
PASSWORD = 'secret_password'

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
s.starttls()
s.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD)
#s.sendmail(username, receiver, message)
s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()
```

If you use `print( msg.as_string() )` then you can see how looks mail as text.

```
Subject: Hello
From: your_email@gmail.com
To: a@gmail.com, b@gmail.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============7362581310494790885=="

message for the body.
--===============7362581310494790885==
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.txt"
MIME-Version: 1.0

MQoyCjMK

--===============7362581310494790885==--
```